# What the meaning of T Z for date?

Tags: python, datetime

I am using api it require date as this format

`2020-03-01T00:00:00Z`

I googled around and couldn't under stand what the `T` `Z` means.

For Now I made this string with this code by `python`

```
dt_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

However it looks a bit awkward and I am not sure if it is correct.

Is there any good way for python datetime??

Answer (score 5):

This looks like ISO 8601 time format. The `T` stands for `time` and is used as separator, while `Z` determines time offset and stands for `Zulu` which is commonly used, military originated, name alias for UTC+0 offset. For other offsets you need to specify it as `HH:MM`, with `+` or `-` respectively. So the `Z` is therefore equivalent of writing `+00:00`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 for more info.

Comment: So ,,, I don't need to care T Z  ? just adding letters for time strings?

Comment: For example when I want to get the data by contries.

`apisample.com/us/getinfo?2020-10-10T00:00:00Z`
`apisample.com/fr/getinfo?2020-10-10T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Thia is how it should be formatted if you want to produce ISO8601 compliant stamp. There's no point of reinventing the wheel here - just stick to the standard. You should always care timezone, otherwise it is not clear what the time really is. Instead of `Z` you can have explicit offset, ie `+00:00`

Comment: Also you should only use `Z` if your time stamp is in UTC. If you ie live in other time zone then you use correct offset or convert your stamp to UTC and then use `Z` or you will be producing wrong data

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Just a reminder: "time offset" != "time zone". UTC is not a timezone. Nobody live in a UTC timezone. To @whitebear: python `datetime` modules has `isoformat()`, and it can handle well ISO datetime. Note2: offset `-00:00` may be used for unknown offsets (per RFC3339)

Comment: Correct. Edited my answer. Thanks